# Basic CMS for bookmarks (Delicious clone)

Tags: php, content-management-system, bookmarks, delicious-api

I am looking for a basic open source CMS to build a social bookmarks site like [Delicious](http://delicious.com). I need just basic functionality:

1. Users should have pages like site.com/username where titles and links for the bookmarked sites will be displayed.
2. Ability to check who else added a specific URL to the bookmarks.
3. Bookmarklet to quickly add a site URL to the bookmarks.
4. RSS for the users bookmarks.

I do not need tags, comments, ratings and other complex functions.

I'm looking for the solution for three days in a row, but many projects are closed or are not maintained for a long period of time.

I'm not a programmer, but I can tweak PHP code, HTML and CSS. So it will be better if the CMS is written in PHP, but other languages and frameworks (like [Ruby](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29) on [Ruby on Rails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails) or [Django](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29)) will be fine too if the CMS is simple.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to look at this page:

http://www.codefear.com/scripts/social-bookmarking-script-digg-clone/

List of popular bookmarking clones. Free content management.

Especially Pligg that was nominated last year for best [CMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system).

Comment: Pligg is good for building sites like Digg where voting process is important. I'm looking for more simple solution but thanks anyway. I'll try to adapt Pligg too if I don't not find better CMS.

Comment: removing features is easier than adding it . pligg has a powerful core architecture , btw u should decide what to use in face of features u r looking for

Answer (score 1):

Would GetBoo work for you? http://www.getboo.com/about.php

Comment: GetBoo is a little bit clunky and its admin panel is strange but if I don't find anything better I'll try to modify GetBoo.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Scuttle](http://sourceforge.net/projects/scuttle/). Installation instructions are in the ReadMe file.

Answer (score 0):

There is also [SemanticScuttle](http://semanticscuttle.sf.net/), which is a very active fork of Scuttle.